# jquery, my function is executed a lot of time instead of one

Tags: jquery, function, onclick, mouseover, mouseout

when i'm clicking on .myClass I want 'a ' to appear before #message unfortunately 'a a a a a' appear instead of it.

My css are:

```
    #message{
    width: 80%;
    height: 10%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
}


 .hideIt{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

and my code is:

```
<div id="message">test1 <span class="myClass hideIt">test2</span></div>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {

        test = function() { $('#message').before('a '); }

        $(document).on('mouseover', '#message', function () {
            var el = $(this);
            el2 = el.children('.myClass');
            el2.removeClass('hideIt');
            el2.on('click',test);
            el.on('mouseout', function() {
                el2.addClass('hideIt');
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
```

here a Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/TDJVw/

Comment: You are registering a click handler each time #message is hovered on. You need to either .off() that click handler, or take it outside of the mouseover handler (depends on what you want to accomplish)

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky is the correct syntaxe for .off() is : $(document).off('mouseout', '#message', test); ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TDJVw/8/

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '#message', function () {
    $(this).find('.myClass').removeClass('hideIt');
}).on('mouseout', '#message', function() {
    $(this).find('.myClass').addClass('hideIt');
})

$('#message .myClass').on('click', test);
```

I moved the `click` and `mouseout` event handlers outside of the `mouseover` handler

Edit: oops, I forgot to add #message to the 2nd .on()

Answer (score 2):

Check this fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/TDJVw/1/ it will do what you want.

Your problem was that you was registering the `click` method each time the `div` was hovered. I moved the `click` outside of the `hover` method.

Comment: Your code still registers multiple `mouseout` handlers, which are redundant. you only really need one

Answer (score 0):

If try

```
test = function() { $('#message').html('a '); }
```

This will place 'a' at 'test1' place. Is this your requirement?